# Sorting words out in a string array

Tags: c, arrays, string

My program is designed to allow the user to input a string and my program will output the number of occurrences of each letters and words. My program also sorts the words alphabetically.

My issue is: I output the words seen (first unsorted) and their occurrences as a table, and in my table I don't want duplicates. **SOLVED**

For example, if the word "to" was seen twice I just want the word "to" to appear only once in my table outputting the number of occurrences.

How can I fix this? Also, why is it that i can't simply set `string[i] == delim` to apply to every delimiter rather than having to assign it manually for each delimiter?

Edit: Fixed my output error. But how can I set a condition for `string[i]` to equal any of the delimiters in my code rather than just work for the space bar? For example on my output, if i enter "you, you" it will out put "you, you" rather than just "you". How can I write it so it removes the comma and compares "you, you" to be as one word.

Any help is appreciated. My code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
const char delim[] = ", . - !*()&^%$#@<> ? []{}\\ / \"";
#define SIZE 1000

void occurrences(char s[], int count[]);
void lower(char s[]);


int main()

{

    char string[SIZE], words[SIZE][SIZE], temp[SIZE];

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, n = 0, count;
    int c = 0, cnt[26] = { 0 };

    printf("Enter your input string:");
    fgets(string, 256, stdin);
    string[strlen(string) - 1] = '\0';
    lower(string);
    occurrences(string, cnt);
    printf("Number of occurrences of each letter in the text: \n");
    for (c = 0; c < 26; c++){
        if (cnt[c] != 0){
            printf("%c \t  %d\n", c + 'a', cnt[c]);
        }
    }
/*extracting each and every string and copying to a different place */
    while (string[i] != '\0')

    {
        if (string[i] == ' ')

        {
            words[j][k] = '\0';
            k = 0;
            j++;
        }

        else

        {
            words[j][k++] = string[i];
        }
        i++;
    }

    words[j][k] = '\0';
    n = j;

        printf("Unsorted Frequency:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)

    {
        strcpy(temp, words[i]);
        for (j = i + 1; j <= n; j++)

        {
            if (strcmp(words[i], words[j]) == 0)

            {
                for (a = j; a <= n; a++)
                    strcpy(words[a], words[a + 1]);

                n--;
            }
        } //inner for
    }
    i = 0;

/* find the frequency of each word  */
    while (i <= n) {
        count = 1;
        if (i != n) {
            for (j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
                if (strcmp(words[i], words[j]) == 0) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        /* count - indicates the frequecy of word[i] */
        printf("%s\t%d\n", words[i], count);
        /* skipping to the next word to process */

        i = i + count;
    }
    printf("ALphabetical Order:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)

    {
        strcpy(temp, words[i]);
        for (j = i + 1; j <= n; j++)

        {
            if (strcmp(words[i], words[j]) > 0)

            {
                strcpy(temp, words[j]);
                strcpy(words[j], words[i]);
                strcpy(words[i], temp);
            }
        } 
    }  
    i = 0;
    while (i <= n) {
        count = 1;
        if (i != n) {
            for (j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
                if (strcmp(words[i], words[j]) == 0) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        printf("%s\n", words[i]);
        i = i + count;
    }
    return 0;

}

void occurrences(char s[], int count[]){
    int i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0'){
        if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z')
            count[s[i] - 'a']++;
        i++;
    }
}

void lower(char s[]){
    int i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0'){
        if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z'){
            s[i] = (s[i] - 'A') + 'a';
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood some of the syntax, or made a simple mistake :) `words[i] == NULL;` does nothing as a statement. You compare whatever is at `i` in `words` with `NULL`, `==` is the equality operator. The statement is probably even optimized away by the compiler. It is syntactically valid but does nothing because you don't do anything with the result. Haven't looked at the rest of the code but you most likely want `=` (assignment.)

Comment: lower() is broken:  Replace _s[i] = s[i] + 32_ with _s[i] = (s[i] - 'A') + 'a'_

Comment: Thank you I fixed it Craig.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution to your problem and its name is called `Wall`.  No, not the type to bang your head against when you encounter a problem that you can't seem to solve but for the Warnings that you want your compiler to emit: ALL OF THEM.

If you compile C code with out using `-Wall` then you can commit all the errors that people tell you is why C is so dangerous.  But once you enable Warnings the compiler will tell you about them.

I have 4 for your program:

`for (c; c< 26; c++) {` That first c doesn't do anything, this could be written `for (; c <  26; c++) {` or perhaps beter as `for (c = 0; c <26; c++) {`

`words[i] == NULL` "Statement with no effect".  Well that probably isn't what you wanted to do.  The compiler tells you that that line doesn't do anything.

"Unused variable 'text'."  That is pretty clear too: you have defined text as a variable but then never used it.  Perhaps you meant to or perhaps it was a variable you thought you needed.  Either way it can go now.

"Control reaches end of non-void function".  In C `main` is usually defined as `int main`, i.e. `main` returns an int.  Standard practice is to return 0 if the program successfully completed and some other value on error.  Adding `return 0;` at the end of main will work.

Comment: Thank you I made those edits to avoid the warnings coming up. My original issue is still persisting thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your delimiters.  Anything that is *not* a-z (after lower casing it), is a delimiter.  You don't [need to] care which one it is.  It's the end of a word.  Rather than specify delimiters, specify chars that are word chars (e.g. if words were C symbols, the word chars would be: A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and _).  But, it looks like you only want a-z.

Here are some [untested] examples:

```
void
scanline(char *buf)
{
    int chr;
    char *lhs;
    char *rhs;
    char tmp[5000];

    lhs = tmp;

    for (rhs = buf;  *rhs != 0;  ++rhs) {
        chr = *rhs;

        if ((chr >= 'A') && (chr <= 'Z'))
            chr = (chr - 'A') + 'a';

        if ((chr >= 'a') && (chr <= 'z')) {
            *lhs++ = chr;
            char_histogram[chr] += 1;
            continue;
        }

        *lhs = 0;
        if (lhs > tmp)
            count_string(tmp);

        lhs = tmp;
    }

    if (lhs > tmp) {
        *lhs = 0;
        count_string(tmp);
    }
}

void
count_string(char *str)
{
    int idx;
    int match;

    match = -1;
    for (idx = 0;  idx < word_count;  ++idx) {
        if (strcmp(words[idx],str) == 0) {
            match = idx;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (match < 0) {
        match = word_count++;
        strcpy(words[match],str);
    }

    word_histogram[match] += 1;
}
```

Using separate arrays is ugly.  Using a struct might be better:

```
#define STRMAX        100        // max string length
#define WORDMAX        1000        // max number of strings

struct word {
    int word_hist;                // histogram value
    char word_string[STRMAX];    // string value
};

int word_count;                    // number of elements in wordlist
struct word wordlist[WORDMAX];    // list of known words
```