# Sorting word occurrence in string C programming

Tags: c, string

I have been stuck on this for a while now. I wrote my program to count word occurrence in an inputted string by the user as well to sort the words alphabetically. My issue is my program runs perfectly only if there are spaces in between the words inputted. For example, if I input "to to," my program will count those two words as two different words due to the comma rather than counting it as one word in "to" as I would like it to. It is that issue for all of my delimiters in the array `const char delim[]`. How can I fix this issue in my program? I really appreciate any help! My code is down below:

Edit: I took Bob's suggestion to use strchr() and it worked! My only issue is my program outputs the count for delimiters now. I was thinking of possibly writing an if statement when comparing `words[i]` with `words[j]` to see if they have the same value. Is that the best approach to it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
const char delim[] = ", . - !*()&^%$#@<> ? []{}\\ / \"";
#define SIZE 1000

int main(){
    char string[SIZE], words[SIZE][SIZE], temp[SIZE];

    int a = 0, i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, n = 0, count;
    int c = 0, cnt[26] = { 0 };
    int word = 0;
    int x;
    printf("Enter your input string:");
    fgets(string, SIZE, stdin);
    string[strlen(string) - 1] = '\0';
    lower(string);
    /*extracting each and every string and copying to a different place */
    while (string[i] != '\0'){
        if (strchr(", . - !*()&^%$#@<> ? []{}\\ / \"", string[i]) != NULL){
            words[j][k] = '\0';
            k = 0;
            j++;
        }else   {
            words[j][k++] = string[i];
        }
        i++;
    }

    words[j][k] = '\0';
    n = j;

    printf("Number of occurences of each word unsorted:\n");
    i = 0;
    /* find the frequency of each word and print the results */
    while (i <= n) {
        count = 1;
        if (i != n) {
            for (j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
                if (strcmp(words[i], words[j]) == 0) {
                    count++;
                    for (a = j; a <= n; a++)
                        strcpy(words[a], words[a + 1]);
                        n--;
                }
            }//for
        }
        //word == strtok(string, delim);
        /* count - indicates the frequecy of word[i] */
        printf("%s\t%d\n", words[i], count);
        i = i + 1;
    }//while
    printf("Alphabetical Order:\n");
    /* sort the words in the given string */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        strcpy(temp, words[i]);
        for (j = i + 1; j <= n; j++){
            if (strcmp(words[i], words[j]) > 0){
                strcpy(temp, words[j]);
                strcpy(words[j], words[i]);
                strcpy(words[i], temp);
            }
        } //inner for
    }  //outer for
    i = 0;
    while (i <= n) {
        count = 1;
        if (i != n) {
            for (j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
                if (strcmp(words[i], words[j]) == 0) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        printf("%s\n", words[i]);
        i = i + count;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you heard of functions/methods?

Comment: @MitchWheat yes I have why? Also, have heard of strtok but I am not sure how to use it here.

Comment: then I strongly suggest using them...

Comment: Would it be due to better formatting of the code @MitchWheat?

Comment: Omar, your code is messy and hard to read, and it makes it difficult for another SO user to go in there and try to separate the wheat (no pun intended on @MitchWheat) from the chaff.

Comment: Sorry @TimBiegeleisen my fault I'll start using functions, I thought adding comments would make it easier to understand what each part of the code was doing.

Comment: You said [input "to to," my program will count those two words as two different words due to the comma] but are you sure ? You increment the word count j when a space is read not a comma.

Comment: @BobRun so I should also have it increment when a comma is seen correct? But how can I do that for every delimiter I have set other than extending my code with a very large if statement for each delimiter?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225655/sorting-words-out-in-a-string-array/33248914#33248914

Comment: @Omar I posted an answer that works for all the delimiters you had in your file the trick is to use strchr().

Answer (score 0):

Strip every word of that delimeter before comparing.  Actually you don't even need a list of delimeters because words are 'alpha' other than that it's a delimeter.

Comment: I created the array delim[] for that purpose but I am not sure how to do that. I tried setting string[i] = delim but that did not work.

Comment: use isalpha function in a function that determines if a string has nonalpha

Comment: Oh ok so replace string[i] = ' ' in the first if statement in the first while loop to !isalphastring[i]?

Comment: make sure isalpha takes a char not a string, problem solve.

Comment: I compiled my program right now doing that edit but it still would not count to as two words from the example input of "to to,"

Comment: From the way my program is formatted, is it possible to declare a new char variable ch and set it equal to string[i] so isalpha can take ch?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it works, it is an extract of your own code, a little bit modified, it will give you the count, then you have to write the rest, have fun.

```
#include <string.h>
#define YES 1
#define NO 0

int main(  )
{
  char string[1000];
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int is_this_a_word = 0;

  strcpy( string, " to or not ,tobe" );

  while ( string[i++] != '\0' )
  {
    if ( strchr( ", . - !*()&^%$#@<> ? []{}\\ / \"", string[i] ) != NULL )
    {
      is_this_a_word = NO;
    }
    else
    {
      if ( ! is_this_a_word )
      {
    is_this_a_word = YES;
    j++;
      }
    }
  }

  printf( "I counted %d words", j );
  getchar(  );
}
```